# condition on 2 JSON objects

Tags: json, loops, if-statement

Brief description of the function- If user clicks on button A, a loop should run through the cat.json file and check if object- (jobcategory)"Data2":"B" == (job)"DataB":"B", if yes then display - (job)"DataA":"C" and (job)"DataB":"B" in a div.

I've got Json Data as below.

File name: cat.json

```
{

"jobcategory": [

{"Data1":"A","Data2":"B"},
{"Data3":"C","Data4":"D"}

],

"job":[

{"DataA":"C","DataB":"B"},

{"DataC":"T","DataD":"E"}

]
}
```

myscript.json is as below

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 $.getJSON("cat.json", function(data){
       $.each(data.jobcategory, function(){
             $("ul").append("<li><button>"+this['Data1']+"</button></li><br/>");

       });
  });
  });
```

It display "A" and "B" buttons okay on a page. I need to code so that if user clicks on button "A", a loop should run throufh cat.json and if object- "Data2":"B" == "DataB":"B", display - "DataA":"C" and "DataB":"B" in a div.

Any suugestion please?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: the json you wrote is incorrect, there are too many closing curly brackets, for example {"Data3":"C","Data4":"D"}}.
And also in $("ul").append("<li><button>"+this['Data1']+"</button><br />"); the <br/> should be </li>

Comment: Thanks QuarK, that was a typo while attempting to reduce my data. Sorry about that. Its fixed now.